# How to insert a DataTable with existing Key to a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I am working with VB.NET.. i have a DataTable called "QUESTION", containing 3 fields:

- QuestionNumber (unique integer key)
- QuestionText
- QuestionType

In my SQL Server database I created a Table called "QUESTION" with the same fields.
QuestionNumber is defined as integer unique key, auto increment

Now, when i make a bulk copy to insert the DataTable into the SQL Server, the database overwrites my QuestionNumber from the DataTable and generates new ones (starting from 1 increment 1).

How do i have to change my database setup, that the original QuestionNumbers are copied into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when just using inserting try:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [your table] ON
INSERT INTO [your table] (identityCol, col1,...) VALUES (identityCol, col1,...)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [your table] OFF
```

when bulk copying data you need add special parameter/switch/hint on the command, they are detailed here:

[Keeping Identity Values When Bulk Importing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Look up IDENTITY INSERT. You turn it on. Update the table, then turn it back off.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
```

Please note that you can only have it on for one table at a time. If you turn it on for a different table, it turns off on the last table.

If you insert a value that is higher than the largest existing value, it will reseed itself to that value, so that all new values are greater.

Again, don't forget to turn it off:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF
```

If you're literally doing BULK INSERT, then don't forget the KEEPIDENTITY qualifier, which tells the server NOT to ignore your identity values, otherwise, it will ignore your identify values and generate new ones for the identity column.

[Keeping Identity Values When Bulk Importing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx)

Comment: Thank both for your quick answers. I tried this solution, but now i get a SQL Error:
  ex.Message "Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'IMP_FRAGEN' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column." String

Anyone has a idea?

Comment: Do you have values for the identity column?

Comment: Yes, I found the Problem. As KM wrote in the post below, the bulk copy command needs another parameter. Thank you Marcus!

Comment: @user296575 said `Yes, I found the Problem. As KM wrote in the post below, the bulk copy command needs another parameter. Thank you Marcus!` **shouldn't that be thank you KM**??

Comment: I really thought you meant bulk copy in a more generic sense, but I also thought you had seen KM's bit. I'll add it to mine to make it more complete. Thanks KM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the code which solved my problem. Thank you Marcus and KM!

```
' set identity_insert to on to insert tables with key'
        Command = New SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON", con)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()


'Copy dataTable into MSSQL database'
 Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(cn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dTable.TableName
            Try
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using

        'disable identity_insert'
        Command = New SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF", con)
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```